# How to create a folder and then save a generated text file in that folder in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a folder and then save my automated text file into that folder in VBA. I wrote code that automatically creates a file with data in it and I want to save the file into a user-defined folder. Below is the code that I have tried but it does not work:

```
Sub test()

'Declaring variables
Dim equipID As String, destgroup As String, sourceparmname As String, descript As String
Dim lsb As Integer, msb As Integer, signed As String, sformat As String, units As String
Dim scalefact As Variant, numbits As Integer, decim As Integer
Dim ssystem As String
Dim vDB
Dim FName As String, stream As TextStream
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject, NewFolderPath As String

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
NewFolderPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("")


Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
If Not fso.FolderExists(NewFolderPath) Then
    fso.CreateFolder NewFolderPath
    End If

 'Create txt file
  Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("NewFolderPath\test.txt")

..........
```

I would appreciate any inputs/suggestions :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement

```
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("NewFolderPath\test.txt")
```

is trying to create a file called "test.txt" within the folder called "NewFolderPath" within the current directory.

You want to use

```
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(NewFolderPath & "\test.txt")
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew I was missing something small.  Thank you very much :)